# Can you find the artist?

Tags: cipher, letters

A famous artist is hiding within the following sequence: can you find it?

> $E-12-ACH-94-VERY-21-HE-1-E-11-F-2-ERY-721-ND-61-O-8$

Is it possible to write down:

> Camille Saint-Saëns

?

#### Hint 15th May 20

> Artist's last name is 9 letters length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the answer is:

> BEETHOVEN. Each of the letter/number pairs seems to be all but the first letter of a word paired with its frequency in the English language. I assume this is from a reference, but I was not able to find one that matched exactly. Anyway, by adding in the first letter, one would get: (B)E - 12 - (E)ACH - 94 - (E)VERY - 21 - (T)HE - 1 - (H)E - 11 - (O)F - 2 - (V)ERY - 721 - (E)ND - 61 - (N)O - 8

Update:

> OK, I found it. The reference used is the webpage [The Most Common Words In English](https://world-english.org/english500.htm). The numbers are not the position in the list, but rather the position in the list with the digits *reversed*. When the actual position ends in 0 (for example, EVERY is at position 120), the leading zero is dropped. And no, Camille Saint-Saëns cannot be written this way, as no word on the list starts with ë. Indeed, since the diaeresis is used in English for the second letter in a vowel pair, I'm fairly sure it cannot appear first in *any* English word.

Comment: Nice spotted! You are halfway trough the cipher! Keep looking for the numbers, you are on the right way :) Could you write down Camille Saint-Saëns?

Comment: Exact from start to end ;)